# Elasticsearch behaviour

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I have a question about the expected behaviour of Elasticsearch (version 7.9.1) that I'm having a hard time finding the answer to.

I query Elasticsearch with the help of the `elasticsearch-dsl` (version 7.3.0) library. My code is as follows:

```
item_search = ItemSearch(search, query_facets)
item_search = item_search[0:9999]
res = item_search.execute()
```

Here `search` is a search term for full-text search, and `query_facets` is a dictionary mapping fields to the terms in the fields.

The `ItemSearch` class looks like this:

```
class ItemSearch(FacetedSearch):
doc_types = [ItemsIndex, ]

size = 20

facets = {'language': TermsFacet(field='language.raw', size=size),}

def __init__(self, search, query_facets):
    super().__init__(search, query_facets)

def search(self):
    s = super(ItemSearch, self).search()
    return s
```

The `language` field has many thousands of values, but I limited the return size to `20` since we never want to display more results than around that number anyway.

Now onto my actual question: I would expect that if I pass for example `{'language' : ["Dutch"]}` to `ItemSearch` as the `query_facets` parameter, that Elasticsearch returns the count for "Dutch", whether or not it belongs to the top 20 results. However, this is not the case. Is this the expected behaviour, or am I missing something? And if yes, how can I achieve the result I'm after?

Comment: What version of elastic search ?

Comment: Ah good question, 7.9.1